# React App already deployed - need to find/modify react env variables

Tags: reactjs, variables, environment

Hi I have an already deployed react application.

The issue is it is compiled and I need to see / modify environment variables it is using.

Foe example:
document.getElementById('resub-link').href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SUBSCRIPTIONS_URL}

Comment: Out of curiosity why not update the values, repackage and redeploy?

Answer (score 0):

Good way: replace the value on dev and rebuild for production and deploy it again.
Bad and horrible: replace on the production bundle file the string that you want.